# Dropout Training Parameter

Tags: keras, neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I want the use dropout in a LSTM layer for both training and testing. As per this article:

https://towardsdatascience.com/learning-note-dropout-in-recurrent-networks-part-2-f209222481f8

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(X_len, return_sequences = True, input_shape=(X_len, 1)))
model.add(Dropout(rate=0.2, training=True))
model.add(LSTM(X_len))
model.add(Dropout(rate=0.2, training=True))
model.add(Dense(Y_len))
```

Error I get is:

```
TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'training')
```

Any idea how to fix this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the functional format

```
inp = Input(shape=(X_len, 1))
x = LSTM(X_len, return_sequences = True)(inp)
x = Dropout(rate=0.2)(x, training=True)
x = LSTM(X_len)(x)
x = Dropout(rate=0.2)(x, training=True)
out = Dense(Y_len)(x)

model = Model(inp, out)
model.compile('adam', 'mse')
model.summary()
```